# How to check between two words and add text in between those word if it didnot find it

Tags: powershell, vpn

I am trying to update our VPN profiles AOVPN Device tunnel and User tunnel. I want to update the IpinterfaceMetric from 0 to 9.

I am using a example here

IF file contains data something like:

```
\[AOVPN Device Tunnel\]
IpDnsFlus=0
IpInterfaceMetric=0
NetworkOutageTime=0

\[AOVPN User Tunnel\]
IpDnsFlus=0
IpInterfaceMetric=0
NetworkOutageTime=0
```

So what I am trying to do is to check if there is IpinterfaceMetric in AOVPN Device Tunnel section and if not add IpInterfaceMetric in AOVPN Device Tunnel section. Also samething goes to AOVPN User Tunnel.

I have the script to check in the whole rasphone file but I have to check in section to section and add it in each section if it cannot find it in each section.

Can someone help me on this one please?

```
 [CmdletBinding()]

    Param (

    )

    $RasphonePath = Join-Path -Path $env:appdata -ChildPath '\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk'$RasphoneData = Get-Content $RasphonePath
    $RasphoneData = Get-Content $RasphonePath


    If($RasphoneData.Contains("IpInterfaceMetric=0")){


    Write-Verbose 'Updating IpInterfaceMetric setting in rasphone.pbk...'
    $RasphoneData | ForEach-Object { $_ -Replace 'IpInterfaceMetric=.*', 'IpInterfaceMetric=9' } | Set-Content -Path $RasphonePath -Force

    }

     else {
    Add-Content -Path $RasphonePath -Value "IpInterfaceMetric=9" | Set-Content -Path $RasphonePath -Force
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's regex time!

```
# replace values as needed, of course
$fileContent = Get-Content $Path
$matchStart= [regex]::escape('\[AOVPN Device Tunnel\]')
$matchEnd= [regex]::escape('\[AOVPN User Tunnel\]')
$lineSearched = [regex]::escape('IpInterfaceMetric')

# checks if there is anything between the given lines... or the lines in first place
# add ELSE and whetever control as needed
if ($fileContent -imatch "(?s)$matchStart(.|\s)*?$matchEnd") {

    #  check if the value you are looking is ABSENT
    if ($matches[0] -inotmatch $lineSearched) {

        # if it's absent, adds it righter after $matchStart
        $fileContent = $fileContent -replace "(?s)($startMatch)", "`$1$([Environment]::NewLine)$lineSearched"

        # writes the file
        $fileContent | Set-Content $Path
    }

}
```

`[regex]::escape()` is extremely convenient when you have strings using regex escape characters

likewise, `[Environment]::NewLine` is great to add environment-friendly NewLines automatically. In most of my scripts `Set-Variable -Option Constant -Name NL -Value ([Environment]::NewLine)` is often one of the first lines